# Please identify a book involving characters who can manipulate time

Tags: story-identification, time

I read a book in the last couple years i could have sworn I got off of the New York Times bestseller list, but I'm having a hard time remembering the title - it was the first of a new series and I wanted to go back and see if the others had been written yet.

The storyline involves a youth and his friend that live in a small village - they are cast out of the village and head towards a nearby city.

the protagonist can go back in time and teaches his friend how to leave messages in the past as well... they meet a young girl who can phase out at the cost of slowing her personal time down.

there is a subplot describing the origin of the settlement on the planet - evidently it was a ship from earth that used a new kind of FTL engine. the travel was subconsciously affected by the ship's pilot and they ended up somewhere unexpected. the AI of the ship determined that the pilot was unique and ended up creating a segregated settlement of his ancestors on the planet.

the protagonist, his friend and the girl get in trouble in the city and attempt to escape across the barrier (which causes insanity and fear in those that try to cross) between the different settlements where they meet one of the original AI robots that established the colony after the earth-ship arrived.

Comment: Definitely sounds like **Pathfinder** by Orson Scott Card. The whole series is Pathfinder, Ruins, and Visitors. Totally recommend!!

Comment: This is more of a comment on the existing answer than an answer in its own right.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/115803)

Answer (score 8):

The book you describe sounds like [Pathfinder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathfinder_%28novel%29), which is the first book in Orson Scott Cards's [Pathfinder series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orson_Scott_Card_bibliography#Pathfinder_series).

The second book [Ruins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruins_%28novel%29) was recently released (10/2012).

Comment: Ooh, book 2!  I'm going to have to go look for that.